# Play gif animation in alert box

Tags: android, gif

I want to play gif animation in alert box. I am trying to build using

```
public class Fruits extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruits);

    ImageButton apple = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    apple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Fruits.this);
            GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView(this, "file:///android_asset/apple.gif");
            setContentView(view);
            builder.create().show();
        }

    });

}
```

The GIFWebView Class

```
public class GIFWebView extends WebView {

public GIFWebView(Context context, String path) {
    super(context);
    loadUrl(path);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


}
```

but unable to.

Comment: Can we assume that you're calling builder.create().show() ?

Comment: yes i am calling it. But is the method I am doing correct?

Comment: @Meghs are you trying to make a custom progressbar? if so i can help you in this regard

Comment: No its not a progress bar. Its just a gif animation which will be played on the buttons click in dialog box.

Comment: Can you please update the code with the show() call? The mentioned onClick method is the onClickListener of another button in the activity? The given code snippet actually doesn't give us the full picture.

Comment: ok. gif images can be loaded in webview and vedio view to animate properly but not in imageview . hope u know it.

Comment: Updated the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: builder.create().show(); should go inside your onClick() method. Now, when you click on the apple button, you'll get the dialog.

Comment: yes sorry for the mistake, but its still not working

Comment: Oh ya. I missed this. Instead of the setContentView() inside the onClick, you should have builder.setView(view); setContentView() sets the view for the entire activity, while you need to set it to the dialog.

Comment: Actually the error I am getting is here "new GIFWebView(this, "file:///android_asset/apple.gif");" and the error is "Change Constructor GIFWebView(Context,String) to GIFWebView(OnCLickListener,String)"

Comment: Yes. It is not necessary to extend WebView for your use-case. Instead, you could just use a normal WebView, set it's layout params, and call webView.loadUrl(URL) after calling show().

Comment: Its not working. its giving me error of Null Pointer Exception at onClick Listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure imageButton1 is set as the android:id for a ImageButton inside the activity_fruits layout xml

Please update the code to the below:

```
apple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestKeyboard.this);
            WebView view = new WebView(Fruits.this);
            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.create().show();
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/apple.gif");
        }

    });
```

Comment: Very glad that it was helpful!

Comment: one more thing please, where should I add "finish();"
 so that after one loop of gif the dialog gets disappeared. I tried it putting after "view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/apple.gif");" but it isn't working.

Comment: I am not sure about how to detect the loop completion, but the method to make the dialog disappear is dialog.dismiss(). finish() would finish the entire activity.

Comment: just dialog.dismiss().